# An Array of ArrayLists (Null Pointer Exception)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

i'm currently trying to add items to an generic "array" of arraylists but for some reason i keep getting a null pointer exception. The Structure is initialised and both my array index reference and the reference to the object i'm passing in are both visible within the body of code right before the exception occurs. I'm almost sure its down to the way i either declared the data structure or my way im trying to add it in. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
ArrayList<Site>[] group = (ArrayList<Site>[])new ArrayList[entranceSites.size()];

group[i].add(sIndex(path));
```

`sIndex` is a function I'm using to convert integers to graph sites and the object is not null when I'm passing it in so i'm sure its not the problem. I is initialised and also visible to the program.

Comment: Why does it need to be an array of `ArrayList`?  Why not `ArrayList<ArrayList<Site>>`??

Comment: I would say that `group[i]` is `null` as you've not created an `ArrayList` for that element...but your code is so incomplete as to not to be able to make a judgment call...

Comment: To be honest i'm new to the ArrayList datastructure and felt more comfortable using a generic array as a container. Is it an undesirable approach?

Comment: It's just more work and since you're already using an `ArrayList`...

Comment: Yes, it is undesirable. Generics and arrays do not play nicely together. I would use a `List<List<Site>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have allocated an array of `ArrayList`s, but you have not allocated any actual `ArrayList`s inside that array. The array initially contains all `null` references. So your invocation to `add` is on a `null` reference and thus causes the exception. If you say:

```
group[i] = new ArrayList<Site>();
```

Before you call `add` it will work.

Note that it is generally a bad idea to mix primitive arrays and Java collections, and if you are new to Java, then you should probably stick to collections since they are going to be easier to work with.

You should also be aware that the cast you are making `(ArrayList<Site>[])` is unchecked and will almost certainly generate a warning assuming you have warnings enabled, which **you should be enabling warnings as a beginner**. This is another reason why it is not a good idea to mix generics with primitive arrays.

Answer (score 4):

```
new ArrayList[entranceSites.size()];
```

does not actually initialize the array elements with any constructor. The array will be filled with `enteranceSites.size()` null elements.

You will need to iterate through the array and actually construct `ArrayList` objects.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can set each element of the array to a new `ArrayList` using Java 8:

```
Arrays.setAll(group, n -> new ArrayList<Site>());
```

(The second argument is a function of `n`, the array index, but `n` isn't actually used.  You still need to include it.)

Comment: Thanks a lot bud, you saved the day! Ive been researching how to add to an arraylist of arraylists and ive hit so many dead ends. I fear to ask any more questions here in case i get my ability to question discontinued :(

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of your code fragment, my guess is that you failed to initialize the `ArrayList<Site>` element being added to the array; thus, failing when calling the `List.add()` method. The array itself is properly initialized, but you are trying to add a Site to an ArrayList that has not been initialized properly.

For this to work, you must create your `ArrayList<Site>` object. Once your lists are properly instantiated, you can add them to the array. You can add `Site` objects when creating the list or after you add them to the array. It does not matter when because the space in memory will be already allocated. Suppose a company has sites in many states, for argument sake, New York. All of the sites in that geographical location will be added to the NY list of sites:

```
ArrayList<Site> nySites = new ArrayList<Site>();
Site site1 = new Site();
group[0] = nySites;
group[0].add(site1);  // Now you can call the add() method
```

Comment: Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. The one thing to remember is to always instantiate objects properly before using. In your case, `ArrayList<Site>[]`, there are three objects that need to be instantiated: the array, the `ArrayList`, and the `Site`.  It is a common mistake to instantiate the array and not the objects it may contain.